# jquery horizontal scroll with mousewheel

Tags: jquery, scroll, mousewheel

I currently have a site that is a sidescroller (http://www.studioimbrue.com) and I'm trying to bind a mousewheel to scroll sideways. Currently I'm using the one found at thehorizontalway.com (called thw.js) but it doesn't seem to work in all browsers (Chrome).

I'm trying to get this one to work: http://brandonaaron.net/code/mousewheel/docs , to simply scroll the whole window, nothing else. There is very limited documentation so I can't figure it out. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834004/slider-with-buttons-how-to-improve/2834891#2834891) about scrolling a div horizontally, I also included some code to use the mousewheel or just grab and drag with the mouse... maybe some of that code will give you an idea?

To elaborate a bit, the mousewheel function gives you the event object and the delta.

```
$('#container').bind('mousewheel', function(event,delta){
 if (delta > 0) {
   // mousewheel is going up; 
 } else {
   // mousewheel is going down 
 }
});
```

The value of `delta` depends on how fast you scroll the wheel. I've seen a range from +50 to -50 if you try really hard :P

Comment: I see what you're saying, but I don't understand the actual "scroll" part. In your other post I see this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 30);  but I can't get that to work in mine. I want the whole window to scroll as opposed to just a div, so I tried changing ('#container') to (window).

Comment: I'm not sure if this is correct, but I got it working in other browsers with this:
$(window).bind('mousewheel', function(event,delta){
 if (delta > 0) {
   window.scrollBy(-80,0);
 } else 
   window.scrollBy(80,0) ;
});

But it seems pretty buggy in Chrome...

Comment: I think it was just my computer at that moment. All is well, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I used the $(window).bind approach in the comments but it wont scroll backwards, only forwards, for both up and down on the wheel.

```
<script>
    $(window).bind('mousewheel', function(event, delta) {
        if (delta > 0) { window.scrollBy(-80,0); 
        } else window.scrollBy(80,0) ; 
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution from the comments above works, but only when moused over the actual element on the page.

```
$(window).bind('mousewheel', function(event, delta) {
    if (delta > 0) { window.scrollBy(-80,0); 
    } else window.scrollBy(80,0) ; 
});
```

When just mousing over empty space (for example, if your content is very short and there's some window left over at the bottom) it'll work for about one scroll, and then break (until you scroll back left), which is why one might think that scrolling only works one way. This also seems to be the case with all of the fancy scroll plugins people recommend for this. Hopefully this helps people find a solution in the future.