# Can I capture horizontal-wheel event with javascript in firefox?

Tags: javascript, events, firefox, scroll

Can I capture horizontal-wheel event with javascript in firefox? ... Specifically, if I a user is using a scroll pad or magic mouse to scroll sideways. I want to capture that. Is it possible?

Comment: Only in the horizontal?Don't considering the vertical?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See here:

[jquery horizontal scroll with mousewheel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842041/jquery-horizontal-scroll-with-mousewheel)

Comment: but that captures vertical scrolling, not horizontal.