# Easy horizontal scrolling

Tags: html, scroll

Let's say I want to make a gallery-like interface, somewhat similar to Windows 8 tiles (and any other interfaces like it, that's just the first that comes to mind at 3AM XD)

It works great on touchscreen devices, I can swipe horizontally, and the interface slides across easily.

But on the computer... it's a pain in the arse. Especially since I'm used to Shift+MouseWheel scrolling horizontally in GIMP XD

Is it possible to make the mousewheel scroll horizontally instead of vertically, or should I build my interface to be vertical instead?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery horizontal scroll with mousewheel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842041/jquery-horizontal-scroll-with-mousewheel) or possibly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346958/how-to-do-a-horizontal-scroll-on-mouse-wheel-scroll

Comment: Absolutely positively never ever suggest jQuery on my questions, please :p

Comment: I did consider that when voting ;) That's where the second link comes in.

Comment: I can not answer, but would like to comment. I believe that you should build the application to scroll the horizonal way. I believe it varies according to what you really want in the project. I personally think that vertical scrolling is better in most cases and horizontal scrolling is more a whim, but like I said it can all vary, all will depend on what is best for your project.

Comment: Hmm... since there will be a scrollbar on computers, I guess the mouse wheel is more of a bonus anyway... I just wish Firefox would be consistent with its mouse wheel events XD