# How to switch vertical and horizontal mouse scroll?

Tags: jquery, scroll, mousewheel, horizontal-scrolling

I have website with horizontal layout and i what to make mouse wheel scroll it relative to axis x (not y, like usual).
I use jQuery plugins [`mousewheel`](http://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel) and [`scrollTo`](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/), but I can't achieve 
 soft, natural scroll.
You can look at the example on my [test site](http://benjamin.dev.informa.ru/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do a horizontal scroll on mouse wheel scroll ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346958/how-to-do-a-horizontal-scroll-on-mouse-wheel-scroll)

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work in Chrome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I [answered a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834004/slider-with-buttons-how-to-improve/2834891#2834891) similar to this... we ended up not using jQuery animation because it was choppy. Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MvRdD/1/).

Try changing the delta multiplier to change the amount the mousewheel scrolls:

```
this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 30);
```