# jquery image panning

Tags: jquery

I have a large image that is within a smaller div.
I need the image to pan, when clicked which i have done using ui scrollable.

I now need a similar panning function but when up, down, left or right navigation arrows is clicked as on google maps for example

how could I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834004/slider-with-buttons-how-to-improve/2834891#2834891) some time back... it only scrolls horizontally, but you should be able to adapt it to scroll vertically as well. It includes click and dragging the image using the mouse and using the mousewheel (for horizontal panning in the demo, I don't know what to tell you about getting the wheel to work in two dimensions).

Check out [the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MvRdD/1/)